# EnsureUser has a limitation?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, forms-authentication, claims

We're converting all SP permissions into ActiveDirectory groups (one per uninherited object, per role level). I wanted the group names to reflect where the permissions were/are, so I assigned each group with a name that matched the site structure:

`sitecollection|site|list|Full Control`

Active Directory had issues with the pipes and the potential length, so I reconfigured everything to use the description of the Active Directory object instead. The actual CN of the group is `-someNumber-` (-1-,-2-, etc).

I ran across an interesting phenomena while adding the groups into SharePoint under the same role level; I had to start the groups at 1000 else the EnsureUser couldn't find the group no matter what.

`$web.EnsureUser('c:0-.f|myprovider|-1-')` says it doesn't exist, whereas `$web.EnsureUser('c:0-.f|myprovider|-1000-')` does just fine.

Is there some sort of limitation to the number of characters a SAM Account Name / Principal Name must be when being searched by SharePoint?

Comment: have you tried this one $claim = New-SPClaimsPrincipal -Identity corp\servero -IdentityType WindowsSamAccountName
$web.EnsureUser($claim.ToEncodedString());

The ToEncodedString() method returns a value like this:  i:0#.w|domain\\username

Comment: We have a Windows Zone set up for our intranet, but all of the accounts I'm dealing with are all going to be on our internet zone - which is only claims based. I can get the `c:0-.f|myprovider|groupname` just fine, and any group with -1000- or more is found as well. I just tried to run the command using the format you suggested, and the group name (which will show in SharePoint to all of our users) returned as `c:0+.w|[SID]`, which won't work.